# More Difficult Yet

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, collocations

I have a question about a particular sense of the adverbs "***still***" and "**yet**":

> to a greater extent or degree

Most dictionaries has the entry above for both "***still***" and "***yet***".  So, the following are standard English:

> 1. It was a ***still*** more difficult problem.
> 2. It was a ***yet*** more difficult problem.

But dictionaries seem to allow a alternative placement for "***still***", so the following is possible for using "***still***":

> 3. The problem was more difficult ***still***.

No such alternative placement for "***yet***" is suggested in dictionaries, to allow the following:

> 4. The problem was more difficult ***yet***.

Is sentence 4 standard English overlooked by dictionaries?

Comment: #4 is a stylised rearrangement of *The problem was **yet** more difficult,* but all  such usages of ***yet*** to mean ***still*** are probably at least "dated", if not actually archaic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So, the pattern in sentence 4 is actually standard English?

Comment: Define "standard". I wouldn't be surprised to encounter it in a Victorian text, but it's not exactly idiomatic in *current* English. But then again I don't much like your example #3 either, and I rather suspect that was never particularly likely even in Victorian times.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is it fair to say that any of the OP's sentences might be encountered in contemporary writing, but that none of them are likely to be encountered in contemporary speech? In common speech, neither _still_ nor _yet_ would be used, I think. Instead, we might hear something like _The problem was even more difficult._

Comment: Nice question, @meatie.

Comment: Taking ngram with the grain of salt: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more+_ADJ_+yet%2Cmore+_ADJ_+still&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmore%20_ADJ_%20yet%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmore%20_ADJ_%20still%3B%2Cc0

Comment: With the superlative the story's much different.

Comment: @P. E. Dant: If by "contemporary writing" you mean *everything* written in recent decades, then yes - we do still see it. But I think it would practically always be in the context of historical fiction, mock-historical fantasy, and "facetious" usages. As you say, today it's [***even**,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+yet+harder%2Cwas+even+harder%2Cwas+still+harder&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20yet%20harder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20even%20harder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20still%20harder%3B%2Cc0) not **yet** harder*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Three Google pages into the modern corpus, I found only [one](https://books.google.com/books?id=tQS4CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT65&dq=%22more+difficult+yet%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiEqOmfkYbPAhXEWSYKHe03CI8Q6AEIMDAD#v=onepage&q=%22more%20difficult%20yet%22&f=false) from 2008 and [one](https://books.google.com/books?id=3zXl7OxZiz4C&pg=PT188&dq=%22more+difficult+yet%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW67nmkYbPAhUB3yYKHY7ND9k4MhDoAQhdMAs#v=onepage&q=%22more%20difficult%20yet%22&f=false) from 2011. "Yet" is used pretty frequently in this sense, though, in the dependent clause _More difficult yet._

Answer (score 0):

> No such alternative placement for "yet" is suggested in dictionaries,
>   to allow the following:
>
> The problem was more difficult yet.

If not suggested, does it mean not allowed? No. You can use the sentence as is.

Anyway...

The problem was more difficult still. = The problem was more difficult *in spite of that* = [in spite of something not mentioned]; or *even* (more difficult).

The problem was more difficult yet. = The problem was more difficult *still more* (difficult) or *even* (more difficult).

However, and though both are used as different parts of speech with different definitions, only *yet* is a *conjunction*, which might explain that it is not used at the end of a sentence or as the last word because it is a *subordinating conjunction* used primarily to introduce an adverb dependent clause.

The problem was more difficult, *yet* he *was determined* to fix it. [*yet* modifies the verb phrase *was determined*]

Put another way, *yet* as the last word can be misleading. Is it modifying *difficult* or is there a missing clause?

Still it is used at the end of a sentence.

http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/yet

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/yet_1